# custom update and delete queries in spring boot for postgresql

Tags: spring-boot, postgresql-9.5

hi I am trying to update and delete the data in my application in spring boot and I came to know that postgresql is quite different from normal SQL can you provide the correct syntax for the update and delete operations in postgresql for spring boot application please I couldn't find it in internet.

Answer (score 0):

If you use Spring Boot you actually could use Spring Data for creating queries and you'll not need to write queries by yourself.

Comment: Thank a lot for the suggestion. we have changed to mongodb now